# Php doesn't effect mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem with accessing my mySQL database through php. I use

`$sql ="UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username='nanobots'";`
The problem is that `UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username='nanobots'` works fine when I enter it into the database through phpMyAdmin, but when I try to change the database through the php code, it doesn't work. Is this a problem with my database permissions? If so, how would I go about changing it?

Here's the full code:

```
<?php


 $server = 'mysql.hostinger.co.uk';
 $user = 'u551200555_nano';
 $pass = '12345';
 $db = 'u551200555_logsy';


 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) 
 or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
 mysql_select_db($db) 
 or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());


 $sql ="UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username='nanobots'";

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if your code is incomplete, but I don't see where you are actually sending your query to the database. Eg: `mysql_query($sql);` and, BTW mysql functions are depreciated in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use [mysql_ as it is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should rewrite your code to (at least) this:

[**mysqli_:**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

```
define ('HOST','mysql.hostinger.co.uk');
define ('USER','u551200555_nano');
define ('PASS','12345');
define ('DB','u551200555_logsy');

$con = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);
if ($con->errno) { exit('No connection'.$con->error);}

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET adagio = 1 WHERE username='nanobots'");
```

The `define` part should be in a extra file, best if not in your webroot. Instead of the query statement, you should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

[**PDO:**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
....
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);
```

**SIDENOTE:**

You have to run every query, you were basically only assigning a string to a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been learning php-MySQL interactions from some old guides, but I guess I have to look for newer ones now ;)

Answer (score 5):

Your code isn't executing a SQL statement on the database. It's just setting a variable to a string value. (There's nothing special about the name of the variable `$sql`. It could be `$foo` or whatever.)

New development should be using mysqli or PDO interface, not the deprecated mysql interface.

Comment: For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Note that the original mysql drivers that you are using are depreciated and wont work if you upgrade to php > 5.5. You may want to use mysqli or PDO instead.

```
// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
...
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
....
$statement = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did was just an assignment operation, you just assign a string to a variable $sql. If u want it to execute you have to put it in php query function. E.g mysqli_query($sql); or  mysql_query($sql);